# How can i eliminate the if conditions in this scenario

Tags: java

I have  a Program as shown below 
in which i am checking the open value with different conditions (to how much extent the buyer price is greater than or less than open price )

Is there any better way to handle this

```
 package com;

import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double firstbuyer1 = 1.34;
        double firstbuyer2 = 2.34;
        double firstbuyer3 = 3.45;
        double firstbuyer4 = 2.45;
        double firstbuyer5 = 1.50;

        double open = 3.40;

        int positivevalue =0;
        int lessthan2 =0;
        // checking the positive conditions
        if(firstbuyer1==open||firstbuyer1-open<0.50)
        {
            positivevalue = positivevalue+1;
        }

        if(firstbuyer2==open||firstbuyer1-open<0.50)
        {
            positivevalue = positivevalue+1;
        }

        if(firstbuyer3==open||firstbuyer1-open<0.50)
        {
            positivevalue = positivevalue+1;
        }

        if(firstbuyer4==open||firstbuyer1-open<0.50)
        {
            positivevalue = positivevalue+1;
        }

        if(firstbuyer5==open||firstbuyer1-open<0.50)
        {
            positivevalue = positivevalue+1;
        }
            //      // checking the negative conditions

        if(firstbuyer1-open<2)
        {
            lessthan2 = lessthan2;
        }

        if(firstbuyer2-open<2)
        {
            lessthan2 = lessthan2+1;
        }

        if(firstbuyer3-open<2)
        {
            lessthan2 = lessthan2+1;
        }

        if(firstbuyer4-open<2)
        {
            lessthan2 = lessthan2+1;
        }

        if(firstbuyer5-open<2)
        {
            lessthan2 = lessthan2+1;
        }


        // similarly i need to write for lessthan 3 , lessthan 4 , lessthan 5 


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Why are you doing the same ifs 5 times in a row?

Comment: "if(firstbuyer1==open||firstbuyer1-open<0.50)" is a bit often there or? Please format your code a bit nicer like "lessthan2+1;" into  "lessthan2 + 1;" -- "if(firstbuyer2-open<2)" "if (firstbuyer2 - open < 2)" that would improve readability:-)

Comment: Create a list/array/whatever of buyers and apply the logic to every element contained?!

Comment: sorry it is a typo mistake , i am updating my question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring 5 different variables as follows -

```
double firstbuyer1 = 1.34;
double firstbuyer2 = 2.34;
double firstbuyer3 = 3.45;
double firstbuyer4 = 2.45;
double firstbuyer5 = 1.50;
```

use a collection. e.g. an array as follows -

```
double[] firstbuyers = {1.34, 2.34, 3.45, 2.45, 1.50};
```

Now where the conditions are similar you can utilize a loop. e.g.

```
for(int i = 0; i < firstbuyers.length; i++) {
    // ... refer to current firstbuyer as firstbuyers[i]
    if((firstbuyer[i] - open) < 2) {
        lessthan2 = lessthan2 + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an array.

```
double[] buyer = {1.34, 2.34, 3.45, 2.45, 1.50};
double open = 3.4;
int positivevalue = 0;
int lessthan2 = 0;
for(int a=0; a<buyer.Length; a++)
{
 if(buyer[a] == open || buyer[a]-open<0.50)
   positivevalue++;
 if(buyer[a]-open<2)
   lessthan2++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com;

import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Test extends Thread {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double firstbuyer1 = 1.34;
        double firstbuyer2 = 2.34;
        double firstbuyer3 = 3.45;
        double firstbuyer4 = 2.45;
        double firstbuyer5 = 1.50;

        double open = 3.40;

        int positivevalue =0;
        int lessthan2 =0;
        // checking the positive conditions

        if(firstbuyer1==open||firstbuyer1-open<0.50)
        {
            positivevalue = positivevalue + 5;
        }


        // checking the negative conditions

        if(firstbuyer1-open<2)
        {
            lessthan2 = lessthan2 + 4;
        }



        // similarly i need to write for lessthan 3 , lessthan 4 , lessthan 5 


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that piece of code is not correct in terms of precision. You cannot use double - double < some_other_double. You can try for instance:

```
double d1 =0.83;
double d2= 0.5;
double diff = d1 -d2;
```

that will not produce 0.33 as you might expect but rather 0.32999999999999996.
So the problem in that code is not only the convenient method but rather the correct way. You should use BigDecimal in order to have the correct results. Then you can use a method with the following signature, for instance:

```
boolean isLessThan(BigDecimal d1, BigDecimal d2, BigDecimal lessThanLimit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use functions to encapsulate the condition logic

```
   public class Test extends Thread {

            public static int buyerPositive(double buyer, double open){
                return buyer == open || buyer - open < 0.50 ? 1 : 0;
            }
            public static int buyerNegative(double buyer, double open, int amount) {
                return buyer - open < amount ? 1 : 0;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                double firstbuyer1 = 1.34;
                double firstbuyer2 = 2.34;
                double firstbuyer3 = 3.45;
                double firstbuyer4 = 2.45;
                double firstbuyer5 = 1.50;

                double[] buyers = {firstbuyer1, firstbuyer2, firstbuyer3, firstbuyer4, firstbuyer5 };

                double open = 3.40;

                int positivevalue =0;
                int lessthan2 =0;
                int lessthan3=0;
                int lessthan4 =0;
                int lessthan5 =0;

                for (double buyer : buyers){
                    positivevalue += buyerPositive(buyer, open);
                    lessthan2 += buyerNegative(buyer, open, 2);
                    lessthan3 += buyerNegative(buyer, open, 3);
                    lessthan4 += buyerNegative(buyer, open, 4);
                    lessthan5 += buyerNegative(buyer, open, 5);
                }

            }

    }
```